# One opensource database for traces, metrics and logs data persistence

Tags: database, prometheus, zipkin

I am looking for an open-source database for traces, metrics, and logs data persistence, basically one database for all, my observability stack is opentelemetry, zipkin, prometheus, grafana. Zipkin store data in memory and prometheus uses local storage, if not one database then how should I use different opensource databases for each?

I have already set up the observability stack, I looked for many databases but did not find one solution for all.